# objects are not valid as a react child (found object with keys {$$typeof type key ref props _owner, _store }).

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

objects are not valid as a react child (found object with keys {$$typeof type key ref props _owner, _store }). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I tried all the solution on net also change my firebase version or change import to const still i am getting this error in android. in IOS it working fine please help me in this

Comment: Add *some* code thanks

Comment: I worked on ios mostly I created my whole app and now when i checked it on Andriod then it showing this msg...

Comment: That doesn't really help.. all I can say without any code is "don't try to render an object directly.. either stringify it.. or use one of its properties.. But really long-shotting here since you didnt post any code

Comment: I search everything i feel it is happning dure to firebase used in redux action.. should i also change them too